# Manipulating cells and nested cells

Tags: matlab, cell

I have **P** being a **17x1** cell, each cell representing a subject. Each of the **17** cells within **P** is a **3x1** cell, representing contrast images for each subject. So basically there are **17** subjects, **3** contrast images per subject. So to index the `3rd` contrast images of the `14th` subject, I would do `P{14,1}{3,1}`. However, I would like to turn **P** into **3*17 x 1** cell (or **51x1** cell) instead. This means there are no nested cells within each cell in **P**. So **P** would be something like this:

```
Subject1/contrast1.img

Subject1/contrast2.img

Subject1/contrast3.img

Subject2/contrast1.img

Subject2/contrast2.img

Subject3/contrast3.img

...

Subject17/contrast3.img
```

Could anyone tell me how this may be accomplished?

Comment: you mean 51x1? if so, write a for loop i=0:50 with q{i+1}=p{mod{i,3}+1}{rem{i,3}+1}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I did this: for i=0:50; q{i+1,1}=P{mod(i,17)+1}{rem(i,3)+1};end. However, this gives me an incorrect order of the images. It gives me Subject1/contrast1.img, Subject2/contrast2.img, Subject3/Contrast3.img etc. instead of the order I mentioned in the original message.

Comment: I don't think that's going to give you what you want.

Comment: I tried loop i=0:50 with q{i+1}=p{mod{i,3}+1}{rem{i,3}+1} but this gives me an error with undefined "rem". I changed {1,3} to (1,3) then it works but it keeps repeating the first three subjects. Hence, I changed it to what I have in the previous message. It didn't work either.

Comment: my bad, I was using braces instead of parentheses for the 'mod' and 'rem' functions; this should do:  i=0:50 with q{i+1}=p{mod(i,3)+1}{rem(i,3)+1}

Comment: I figured that. The challenge is that p{mod(i,3)+1} only loops through the first 3 subjects and p{mod(i,17)+1} loops through all 17 subjects but gives me the wrong order of images. All 3 contrasts of the same subjects should be contiguous.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a bit confused today; try this:  i=0:50 with q{i+1}=p{floor(i/3)+1}{mod(i,3)+1}

Comment: @oligilo It sounds like you found the solution. I would recommend you to post it as an answer (perhaps slightly expanded) so this question won't remain open.

Comment: @Dennis It seems that there is another solution that might be better than what I suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a oneliner?

```
a = {{1;2};{3;4};{5;6};{7;8}}
b = vertcat(a{:})
```